# anyone can find the syntax misstake in my php?

Tags: php, syntax

I'm trying to write out the errors, which are created in my .php , as an alert in my .html but i cant get it to run.

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION["error"])){
     echo "<script> alert(".$_SESSION["error"].");";
     echo "</script>";}
    ?>
```

i thnk its just a misstake in the syntax, becuase when i run it in an online php testing program it works

php is enabled in .html and its working 10 lines later :D
in this example its working:

```
<?php if(!isset($_SESSION["login_user"])){
                    echo "<fieldset> <form id='login' method='post' action='../php/login.php'>";
                    echo "<input type='text' name='email' placeholder='E-Mail Adresse' required>";
                    echo "<input type='password' name='passwort' placeholder='Passwort' required><br/>";
                    echo "<a href='registrierung.html'>Registrieren</a>";
                    echo "          <input name='submit' id='anmelden' type='submit' value='Login'>";
                    echo "      </form>";
                    echo "</fieldset>";
                    }
                    else{
                    //Hier Html für eingeloggt Kasten Bitte
                    }
                ?>
```

Comment: Keep the file extension as .php instead .html

Comment: There are no sytax errors here, but if you have a *.html file (unless you have this configured in your webserver), the php code will not be persed and executed. Also can you explain how are your 2 file connected? What is calling what? Aslo `alert(".$_SESSION["error"].")` will result in `alert(error message here)` and this will cause a JS error

Comment: @Auris, should have tested it, was just confused that phpstorm errors this out, but yea its worikng totally fine :D the woirking code is      <?php if(isset($_SESSION["error"])){
            echo "<script> alert('".$_SESSION["error"]."');</script>";
       unset($_SESSION["error"]);
                  }?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never done such an error handling. 
But if you want to alert a String in JavaScript ist has to be in quotes. 
So I think it has to be: 
        echo " alert(' ".$_SESSION["error"]." '); ";